# How to make table view load data from Firebase Firestore after array is appended in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I have this case where I get data from Firebase, put it in array, and populate it in my `Table View`.
But the `Table View` loads the data before the function finishes to append data into the array.
Therefore, I always get `Index out of range` error.

If you guys have any other solution to my case, feel free to correct my code.
But for now, I only can think a way on how to make the function append the data into the array before `Table View` load it.

Hopefully you guys get what I mean.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

var arrayCurrentProduct = [currentProduct]()
var arrayRetrievedData: [String:Any] = [:]
var arrayConvertedPrice: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func initProduct(selectedProduct: String) {
    arrayCurrentProduct = referProduct(productName: selectedProduct)
}

private func referProduct(productName: String) -> [currentProduct] {
    switch productName {
    case Product.Microsoft.rawValue:
        getPrices(document: "Msft") { (_) in
            self.convertPrice(Type: "std")
            self.convertPrice(Type: "dc")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    default:
        break
    }
    return arrayCurrentProduct
}

private func getPrices(document: String, completion: @escaping (_ String:Any?) -> Void) {
    retrievePrice(document: document) { [weak self] (data) in
        guard let self = self else {return}
        self.arrayRetrievedData = data
        completion(self.arrayRetrievedData)
    }
}

private func convertPrice(Type: String) {
    formatterCode(formatter: formatter)
    var priceFormatted = ""
    guard let price = arrayRetrievedData[Type] else {return}
    if let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: price as! NSNumber) {
        priceFormatted = formattedPrice
    }
    arrayConvertedPrice.append(priceFormatted)
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellShowing = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ShowingTVCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShowingTVCell
    let cellInput = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InputTVCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InputTVCell
    
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cellShowing.labelName.text = microsoft[indexPath.row]
        cellShowing.labelPrice.text = arrayConvertedPrice[indexPath.row] // Error index out of range
        return cellShowing
    case 1:
        cellInput.labelSpec.text = microsoft[indexPath.row]
        return cellInput
    default:
        return cellShowing
    }
}
```

Here's a bit of the flow:

I select a product, `initProduct()` called --> `referProduct()` called --> get price from Firebase --> convert price to currency, append to array --> loaded by `Table View`

I've also tried to put `reloadData()` in some places but it didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
```

You wrote a magic number (4) before the fetching data. tableView try to create a 4 row per section with no data. You should update your numbersOfRowsInSection return value after fetching data.

Comment: my bad, I didn't miss the line, I just didn't put it here.
I'll update the code real quick

Comment: I also changed my answer too :)

Comment: man why I didn't think of that before. I made that number of rows as I wanted when I begin the project.
Thanks for saving my day!